# Go cross-compilation with 1.5.x - output file is overridden

Tags: go

I'm using `go 1.5` and I'm cross compiling like specified [here](http://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5).

The problem is that when compiling the project it will override the binary the last compilation created. Moreover - I will never know which OS/ARCH the executable file that I'm running was compiled to (in any case that is not windows).

Is there a way to rename the file at compile command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the "-o" argument, like this:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=386 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o test/output/myapp
```

Answer (score 2):

From the page you linked to:

> -o may be used to alter the name and destination of your binary, but remember that go build takes a value that is relative to your $GOPATH/src, not your working directory, so changing directories then executing the go build command is also an option.

If you use `GOOS` and `GOARCH` in the name, you should be able to achieve what you want.